# Assign Value to Column Based on Range of Two Columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to assign a TRUE or FALSE to a new column (Working Hours) based on two columns time. I would like to state TRUE when time is within a certain range and FALSE when time is outside of that range. I am using the following code - but having issues with it properly assigning the TRUE/FALSE values:

My df is called ALLOBS and column From contains the time started and column To contains the time completed.

```
     Date     From    To          Location                Working Hours
1   1/28/2010 00:00   07:45        No Location            NA
2    3/2/2010 07:45   16:30        Kahana                 NA
3    3/3/2010 08:00   16:15        Waikiki                NA
4    3/4/2010 09:00   16:45        Kahana                 NA
5    3/5/2010 16:31   00:00        No Location            NA
6    3/6/2010 12:00   13:15        Waikiki                NA
7    3/7/2010 13:14   16:31        Kahana                 NA
8    3/8/2010 07:00   12:00        Honolulu               NA
```

I would like to write TRUE when the time is between 07:30 (From) and 16:30 (To), and FALSE when the time is between 16:31 (To) and 07:29 (From). Thank you!

Comment: Please provide what your final desired result should look like. In your example, which rows are `TRUE` and `FALSE`? Do the time ranges for those dates need to be completely inside your interval from 7:30-16:30? Or just overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about what your data look like and which of two options below you desire. Uses `dplyr` and `lubridate`

The question is what to do about row 5 where the `From` is definitely after 07:30 and the `To` is technically before 16:30 (although it is probably meant to be 00:00 the next day or 23:59 the same day?

```r
ALLOBS
#>        Date  From    To    Location
#> 1 1/28/2010 00:00 07:45 No Location
#> 2  3/2/2010 07:45 16:30      Kahana
#> 3  3/3/2010 08:00 16:15     Waikiki
#> 4  3/4/2010 09:00 16:45      Kahana
#> 5  3/5/2010 16:31 00:00 No Location
#> 6  3/6/2010 12:00 13:15     Waikiki
#> 7  3/7/2010 13:14 16:31      Kahana
#> 8  3/8/2010 07:00 12:00    Honolulu
```

Option #1 is what I think you want making row # 5 `FALSE` by checking for `From` < 16:31

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ALLOBS %>%
   mutate(Working_hours =
             hms(paste0(From, ":00")) >= hms("07:30:00") &
             hms(paste0(To, ":00")) < hms("16:31:00") &
             hms(paste0(From, ":00")) < hms("16:30:00")
   )
#>        Date  From    To    Location Working_hours
#> 1 1/28/2010 00:00 07:45 No Location         FALSE
#> 2  3/2/2010 07:45 16:30      Kahana          TRUE
#> 3  3/3/2010 08:00 16:15     Waikiki          TRUE
#> 4  3/4/2010 09:00 16:45      Kahana         FALSE
#> 5  3/5/2010 16:31 00:00 No Location         FALSE
#> 6  3/6/2010 12:00 13:15     Waikiki          TRUE
#> 7  3/7/2010 13:14 16:31      Kahana         FALSE
#> 8  3/8/2010 07:00 12:00    Honolulu         FALSE
```

Option #2 omits that check and therefore concludes `TRUE`

```r
ALLOBS %>%
   mutate(Working_hours = hms(paste0(From, ":00")) > hms("07:30:00") &
             hms(paste0(To, ":00")) < hms("16:31:00"))
#>        Date  From    To    Location Working_hours
#> 1 1/28/2010 00:00 07:45 No Location         FALSE
#> 2  3/2/2010 07:45 16:30      Kahana          TRUE
#> 3  3/3/2010 08:00 16:15     Waikiki          TRUE
#> 4  3/4/2010 09:00 16:45      Kahana         FALSE
#> 5  3/5/2010 16:31 00:00 No Location          TRUE
#> 6  3/6/2010 12:00 13:15     Waikiki          TRUE
#> 7  3/7/2010 13:14 16:31      Kahana         FALSE
#> 8  3/8/2010 07:00 12:00    Honolulu         FALSE
```

Your data (I think)

```r
ALLOBS <- data.frame(
   Date = c("1/28/2010", "3/2/2010", "3/3/2010",
            "3/4/2010", "3/5/2010", "3/6/2010",
            "3/7/2010", "3/8/2010"),
   From = c("00:00", "07:45", "08:00", "09:00", "16:31",
            "12:00", "13:14", "07:00"),
   To = c("07:45", "16:30", "16:15", "16:45", "00:00",
          "13:15", "16:31", "12:00"),
   Location = c("No Location","Kahana", "Waikiki", "Kahana",
                "No Location", "Waikiki", "Kahana", "Honolulu")
)
```